# Candlestick in Java ZK

Tags: java

I have trouble to implement candlestick in java zk.
Please help me but not give me the resource http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/chart/candlestick_chart and http://www.zkoss.org/zksandbox/#d2 because i have see

Comment: What all you have tried and what the issue you got ?

Comment: You need to post your code and mention where's your problem